# Property of deserialized JSON objects are always null only in repository class

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

I have a simple `GET` function in my controller to return a small list of objects from my repository. One of the properties on each of the objects is always null ONLY in the repository class, but not the dbcontext itself when it initially gets populated. I'm just using an `InMemoryDatabase` for this.

Here's my Home.cs model class:

```
public class Home
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public Address Address { get; set; } // this is what is null

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number of rooms is required")]
    public int NumRooms { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 5, ErrorMessage = "Must give a rating between 1 and 5")]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the Address.cs model:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ZipCode is required")]
    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my `Main` function in `Program.cs` where I'm making a call to generate some data:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<RepositoryContext>();

            DataGenerator.SeedData(context);
        }
        host.Run();
    }

    // rest of Program.cs
}
```

Here's the `DataGenerator` class:

```
public class DataGenerator
{
    public static void SeedData(RepositoryContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Homes.Any())
        {
            var homeData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Data/Homes.json");
            var homes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Home>>(homeData);
            context.AddRange(homes);
            context.SaveChanges();
        } // I verify here that the home objects in context DO have valid Addresses
    }
}
```

Here is the `Homes.json`:

```
[
  {
    "Address": {
      "City": "CityOne",
      "State": "MA",
      "ZipCode": "44444"
    },
    "NumRooms": "4",
    "Rating": "4"
  },
  {
    "Address": {
      "City": "CityTwo",
      "State": "MA",
      "ZipCode": "3333"
    },
    "NumRooms": "3",
    "Rating": "3"
  },
  {
    "Address": {
      "City": "AnotherCity",
      "State": "MA",
      "ZipCode": "22222"
    },
    "NumRooms": "2",
    "Rating": "2"
  },
  {
    "Address": {
      "City": "SomeCity",
      "State": "MA",
      "ZipCode": "11111"
    },
    "NumRooms": "1",
    "Rating": "1"
  }
]
```

Here's the Dbcontext class:

```
public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Home> Homes{ get; set; }

    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Here's the relative bits in the `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("Homes"));
    services.AddScoped<IHomeRepository, HomeRepository>();
    // rest of function
}
```

The `HomeRepository` class:

```
public class HomeRepository : IHomeRepository
{
    private readonly RepositoryContext _context;

    public HomeRepository(RepositoryContext context)
    {
        _context = context; // context shows addresses as null here
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Home>> GetHomes()
    {
        var homes = await _context.Homes.ToListAsync(); // address is null here for all home objects
        return homes;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the related controller class:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHomeRepository _repository;

    public HomeController(IHomeRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetHomes()
    {
        var homes = await _repository.GetHomes(); // address is null here for all objects
        return Ok(homes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to include `Address` entity. That's the reason why `address` didn't appear.
 Add `.Include(h=>h.Address)` to `Homes`.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Home>> GetHomes()
    {
        //var homes = await _context.Homes.ToListAsync(); // address is null here for all home objects
        
        var homes = await _context.Homes.Include(h=>h.Address).ToListAsync(); // include address table

        return homes;
    }
```

> Screenshot

[image]

It works.

BTW,This is the most detailed question I have ever seen. :D

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great. I didn't realize you had to use `.Include` when the model was already in another. So If I had multiple model classes inside another, I'd have to chain `.Include` calls together?

Comment: I don't want to sound ungrateful, but IMO the question has too much detail. It doesn't looks like a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to me

Comment: @pfinferno yes you could chain multiple includes. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data